# How can I make each of my Google Chrome shorcuts open my javascript files in my desktop

Tags: google-chrome

The question is pretty stupid ,I know but I need to know.

I want each of my Google Chrome shorcuts open different files from different locations for example, I create a shorcut go to proprieties and change the 
Destiny : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" to "C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\Timers 3mintimer"
But it doesn't work it says the destiny is not valid.

The the file " 3mintimer " is the file I want to open.

I searched and the only thing I find is keyboard shorcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it in Destiny :
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -k "C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\Timers 3mintimer"